# Prepend to start of WordPress nav loop

Tags: menus, navigation

I am trying to add some markup before the `<ul>` tag of a WordPress menu using a custom Walker, which extends `Walker_Nav_Menu`, however I can't get any of my custom markup displaying on the front-end of my site.

I don't get any errors, just nothing added to the generated loop when using `wp_nav_menu` with the `walker` param. Here's the code I'm using to build my custom Walker and the code to call it:

```
class BP_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= '<input type="checkbox" id="responsive-nav-toggle" />

                    <label class="c-nav__collapsible-label" for="responsive-nav-toggle">
                        Explore this section... <i class="c-icon c-icon-down-open"></i>
                    </label>';
    }
}
```

And the `wp_nav_menu()` call:

```
$args = array(
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'c-nav c-nav--vertical c-nav--collapsible',
    'menu_class' => 'c-nav__collapser',
    'theme_location' => 'secondary',
    'walker' => new BP_Walker_Nav_Menu()
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Could anyone help, please? Thanks!

Comment: the method `start_lvl` does nothing with `$output`. maybe you need to echo or return something ?

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not quite sure what you mean. I understand that something needs to be returning for `$output` to be echoed, but where would this need to happen, inside the `start_lvl` function?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Walker in this instance you can use the `items_wrap` parameter of [wp_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

```
$args = array(
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'c-nav c-nav--vertical c-nav--collapsible',
    'menu_class' => 'c-nav__collapser',
    'theme_location' => 'secondary',
    'items_wrap' => menu_wrapper()
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

In the called function you can use the [arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for `%1$s` (id), `%2$s` (class), and `%3$s` (all the list items).

```
function menu_wrapper() {
    $wrap = '<input type="checkbox" id="responsive-nav-toggle" />'
    . '<label class="c-nav__collapsible-label" for="responsive-nav-toggle">'
    . 'Explore this section… <i class="c-icon c-icon-down-open"></i>'
    . '</label>'
    . '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">'
    . '%3$s'
    . '</ul>';

    return $wrap;
}
```